# Removing words from list, only first if statement is being executed

Tags: python

I have a long list of hard to decipher text, each 'line' is cutoff by parentheses (only included one because I can't get this program to work on even one line):

```
"Thyroid Disorders   Understanding Concepts  Kaplan Endocrine Focused Review Tests   n/a 88% (35/40)"
```

I am trying to format it like this and will append it to a file:

```
"Thyroid Disorders Understanding Concepts 88% (35/40)"
```

So I need to remove the strings 'Kaplan', 'Endocrine', 'Focused', 'Review', 'Tests' and 'n/a' from each string and get rid of tabs/newlines.

Here is my code:

```
text = """Thyroid Disorders Understanding Concepts  Kaplan Endocrine A  Focused Review Tests    n/a 88% (35/40)
"""

line = ''
for character in text:
    line = line + character # append every character to string
    if character == ')': #  closing parenthesis signals end of one line
        print('Original line: '+ line) # sanity check 
        line_as_list = line.split() # removes tabs/newlines and makes it easier to remove certain strings
        for word in line_as_list: # loop through each list item, remove if needed
            if word == 'Kaplan':
                line_as_list.remove(word)
                print(line_as_list) # another sanity check, 'Kaplan' is gone

            if word == 'Endocrine': # never runs
                line_as_list.remove(word)
                print(line_as_list )
            
            # Intentionally left out the rest of the words that need to be removed
```

This returns the following:

```
"Original line: Thyroid Disorders    Understanding Concepts   Kaplan Endocrine A   Focused Review Tests n/a   88% (35/
40)"
['Thyroid', 'Disorders', 'Understanding', 'Concepts', 'Endocrine', 'A', 'Focused', 'Review', 'Tests',
'n/a', '88%', '(35/40)']
```

The code under the first `if` statement executes how I intended it to, but the code block under `if word == 'Endocrine'` never runs.

I've tried

```
if word == 'Kaplan' or word == 'Endocrine':
  line_as_list.remove(word)
```

and

```
if word == 'Kaplan':
  line_as_list.remove(word)
elif word == 'Endocrine':
  line_as_list.remove(word)
```

both to no effect, 'Kaplan' is the only word that gets removed. Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: A lot of answers very fast. Thank you guys! Saved me a lot of trouble, I was manually doing this in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
text = "Thyroid Disorders Understanding Concepts  Kaplan Endocrine A  Focused Review Tests    n/a 88% (35/40)"
words_to_remove = {'Kaplan', 'Endocrine', 'Focused', 'Review', 'Tests', 'n/a'}
print(' '.join([w for w in text.split() if w not in words_to_remove]))
```

output

```
Thyroid Disorders Understanding Concepts A 88% (35/40)
```

Comment: This is wizardry. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Description of problem

The problem is that you are mutating the list that you are currently iterating through. Since `Kaplan` and `Endocrine` are right after each other, Endocrine would be skipped as a result since it takes over the index of `Kaplan` and the loop continues to the next index (which is the old index of Endocrine). This is easily illustrated if you would add another string between Kaplan and Endocrine in your own code, and you'll see that both are removed, since the word in between would be skipped instead.

### Solution

best practice would be to create a new list without the items you are looking to remove, not mutate the input list.

I would recommend solving it using a list comprehension and create a new list.

```py
text = """Thyroid Disorders Understanding Concepts  Kaplan Endocrine A  Focused Review Tests    n/a 88% (35/40)
"""

line = ''
for character in text:
    line += character # append every character to string
    if character == ')': #  closing parenthesis signals end of one line
        print('Original line: '+ line) # sanity check 
        new_list = [word for word in line.split() if word not in ["Kaplan", "Endocrine"]] # loop through each list item, remove if needed
        print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error here is that remove pulls all elements after it one step back and the iterator doesn't update so after Thyroid was removed,Endocrine is in it's position and is no longer triggered.
A simple workaround will be:

```
text = """Thyroid Disorders Understanding Concepts  Kaplan Endocrine A  Focused Review Tests    n/a 88% (35/40)
"""

line = ''
print([char for char in text.split()])
for character in text:
    line = line + character # append every character to string
    if character == ')': #  ')' signals end of one line
        print('Original line: '+ line) # sanity check 
        line_as_list = line.split()
        if "Kaplan" in line_as_list:
            line_as_list.remove("Kaplan")
        if "Endocrine" in line_as_list:
            line_as_list.remove("Endocrine")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and explanation as to what is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
for word in line_as_list:
```

to:

```
for word in line_as_list.copy():
```

That way when you remove 'Kaplan' from your original list it won't affect the iteration over the list.

Comment: This has a problem that in each word check you create a copy and in python copy is not so efficient.It would be faster to create a copy at start and start removing from it and looping over original

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa it doesn't work like that. The statement after the 'in' in a for loop is only called once so it doesn't matter

Comment: The overhead of the copies isn't going to make any difference.

Comment: got it I thought the copy was in the if.